# Extract the row with the earliest date if it meets multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, filter

I would like to filter my dataset Based on the following conditions:

- Just for Disease = ABC, and Class = Colonized and the First_Name and Last_Name match, keep the row with the the earliest Spec_Date only.
- Keep all other rows with all other diseases no matter what Class they have and all rows with ABC disease and clinical Class.

  Disease<-c("ABC","ABC","CRE","MCA","ABC","ABC","CRE","MCA")
  Class<-c("Colonized","Colonized","Clinical","Clinical","Colonized","Clinical","Clinical","Clinical")
  First_Name<-c("Roger","Roger","John","John","Roger","Mary","James","Lee")
  Last_Name<-c("Smith","Smith","Doe","Doe","Smith","Poppins","Bond","Majors")
  Spec_Date<-as.Date(c("2001-01-01","2002-01-01","2003-01-01","2003-01-01","2004-01-01","2001-01-01","2003-01-01","2004-01-01"))
  df<-data.frame(Disease,Class,First_Name,Last_Name,Spec_Date)

The resulting dataset should be as below:

```
Disease<-c("ABC","CRE","MCA","ABC","CRE","MCA")
Class<-c("Colonized","Clinical","Clinical","Clinical","Clinical","Clinical")
First_Name<-c("Roger","John","John","Mary","James","Lee")
Last_Name<-c("Smith","Doe","Doe","Poppins","Bond","Majors")
Spec_Date<-as.Date(c("2001-01-01","2003-01-01","2003-01-01","2001-01-01","2003-01-01","2004-01-01"))
df2<-data.frame(Disease,Class,First_Name,Last_Name,Spec_Date)
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: There is a mistake in your example, your input & result are the same. Also, there's no one where 'first and last name are the same', do you mean you want to do this selection within person (unique combinations of first name + last name)?

Comment: Sorry about that. I entered the same dataset by mistake. I already edited my original post. Thank you for detecting that mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

**EDIT**

```
library(dplyr)
    
union_all(
  df %>% 
    filter(Disease != "ABC" | Class != "Colonized"),
  df %>% 
    filter(Disease == "ABC" & Class == "Colonized") %>% 
    group_by(First_Name, Last_Name) %>% 
    summarise(Disease = "ABC",
              Class = "Colonized",
              Spec_Date = min(Spec_Date) %>% as.Date())
)

    
  Disease     Class First_Name Last_Name  Spec_Date
1     CRE  Clinical       John       Doe 2003-01-01
2     MCA  Clinical       John       Doe 2003-01-01
3     ABC  Clinical       Mary   Poppins 2001-01-01
4     CRE  Clinical      James      Bond 2003-01-01
5     MCA  Clinical        Lee    Majors 2004-01-01
6     ABC Colonized      Roger     Smith 2001-01-01
```

Comment: @RazK Please find attached the edited answer

Comment: Hi asd-tm, thank you for the code. This is very helpful. I just have a question. If there are more columns than the columns specified in the sample such as Gender, DOB etc. the code is giving: Error in `union_all()`:
! `x` and `y` are not compatible.
✖ Different number of columns: 7 vs 5.

Comment: @RazK then it will be actually another question. The code does what it should for the specified sample dataset. You may try to add lost columns to `group_by()` thus saving them or produce new columns with requred names in `summarise()`

Answer (score 1):

We need to `group_by` all the involved variables, then `filter` for the `min(Spec_Date)`:

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
    filter(Spec_Date == min(Spec_Date),
           .by = c(Disease, Class, First_Name, Last_Name))

# Or the long form, with `group_by`:

f |> 
    group_by(Disease, Class, First_Name, Last_Name) |> 
    filter(Spec_Date == min(Spec_Date)) |> 
    ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 × 5
  Disease Class     First_Name Last_Name Spec_Date 
  <chr>   <chr>     <chr>      <chr>     <date>    
1 ABC     Colonized Roger      Smith     2001-01-01
2 CRE     Clinical  John       Doe       2003-01-01
3 MCA     Clinical  John       Doe       2003-01-01
4 ABC     Clinical  Mary       Poppins   2001-01-01
5 CRE     Clinical  James      Bond      2003-01-01
6 MCA     Clinical  Lee        Majors    2004-01-01
```

For `slicing` on minnimum and maximum, we can also use the even simpler `slice_min`:

```
df |> 
    slice_min(Spec_Date,
           by = c(Disease, Class, First_Name, Last_Name))
```